# Adding a file path into a formula that is typed into a another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I have

'C:\Users\Documents...etc.......[file name.xlsx]Work Sheet'!$B:$F

in cell B1

i then want to run a vlookup formula to the above file but instead of

vlookup(A1,'C:\Users\Documents...etc.......[file name.xlsx]Work Sheet'!$B:$F,2,false)

I want to use the cell B1 for the path.

Reason is i want the master to look at multiple workbooks and i don't have time to sit and retype.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

VLOOKUP will work on closed workbooks, but INDIRECT won't.  See this post for a few alternatives to INDIRECT on a closed workbook

http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/01/indirect-and-closed-workbooks/

Answer (score 0):

The INDIRECT function will do what you're looking for, i.e.

```
vlookup(a1,INDIRECT(B1),2,false)
```

..but I don't think you can use full paths like your example, vlookup only works within the current workbook as far as I know.